# Androidのログで、 Set no data type icon / Roaming　とは何の事でしょうか

Tags: android

Androidのログを見ていて気になりました。
これはどういう意味ですか、
Dataが無いみたいな事が書かれていますが、何か問題は無いのでしょうか？

```
01-26 21:58:13.535 1317-1317/? D/StatusBar.NetworkController: refreshViews: Data not connected!! Set no data type icon / Roaming
```

Comment: Android6.0/7.0/7.1のAOSPソースを確認しましたが、該当のログが仕込まれているソースはありませんでした。AndroidのVersionはいくつでしょうか？もっともログレベルがDebugなので、エラー等ではなさそうですが。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ここで言われているDataとは「情報」といった意味でなく「データ通信」です。

```
Data not connected!!
データ通信網が接続されていない

Set no data type icon
データ通信なしの場合のアイコンを設定
```

ということになると思います。
「アイコン」が出てきているのはStatusBar.NetworkControllerがログにあるため、ステータスバーに出すアイコンのことを示していると思います。
おそらくSIMなしの端末を使用されている（またはデータ通信網が切れている環境で使用している）ため該当のログが出力されているのではないでしょうか。

Comment: ありがとうございます。
確かに、SIMなしの端末を使用していました。
それと「データ通信」なのですね。